# GAN for inpainting an image

Tags: deep-learning, gan, generative-models

Is it possible to train a GAN model to inpaint an image taken from a specific setting(e.g. an office, woods, beach ...) after we have cropped out people of it?

For example, I used this [repo](https://github.com/JiahuiYu/generative_inpainting)'s pretrained GAN model on Places2

I used a MaskRCNN model to segment people, and then cropped them out :

[image: Original Image]
[image: Image with people Cropped out]

But when I fed the image to the mentioned GAN model, results weren't so great :

[image: Inpainted Image]

If it's possible, what is the best GAN architecture to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would doubt there's a single correct answer for best available architecture, but the current best results come from [this paper by NVIDIA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07723) and [this technical report by Adobe](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03589). The latter paper is the second iteration of the repo you linked. Both papers focus on non-rectangular inpainting, which seems to be your targeted interest. Neither has publicly available code, however, so if you're interested in seeing what those models can accomplish you'll have to re-implement them yourself!

Edit: NVIDIA released a PyTorch implementation since the initial answer, [here's the repo.](https://github.com/NVIDIA/partialconv/)

Comment: Thank a lot, that is in fact what I am looking for. Do you happen to know any good tutorials on implementing a GAN using TensorFlow based on a research paper like these?